# Is it possible to install a node module only for it's types (and bringing in none of its dependencies)

Tags: typescript, npm, types, npm-install

There is a node module which has some type information I need.  It is a front-end module with no important business logic, except that it defines a type it wants to receive from my back-end project.

I will only ever import the module like so:

```
// back-end project
import type { FrontEndType } from "big-giant-front-end-tool"
```

Due to the size of the front-end-tool, I really don't want to make users have to install it and all its dependencies just to use my very small module.

Is it possible to mark a node_module as only existing in the project to be used with the `import type` annotation (and not bringing along any dependencies)?  I suspect not, but perhaps there's some deeper tricks to npm than my imagination projects.

Comment: Are you using some framework in the frontend? Im not an expert in this matter but when using a popular framework or things like webpack, only what is imported and used will increase the bundle size. `type` imports should not increase the size.

Comment: this is a back-end development tool, so while it could benefit in output size from tree-shaking, it won't reduce the dependency size

Comment: Oh I see now. There is probably no way to only install the types. Maybe just put the types into their own module :/